# how to set Name attribute for HiddenField control server-side?

Tags: asp.net, hiddenfield

I want to set the "name" attribute for HiddenField control of ASP.NET from code behind, but I cannot find the "Attributes" property. Is it not there for a purpose? How do I add the attribute?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `name` attribute is automatically computed from the [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx) properties of the hidden field and its ancestors in the [naming container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) chain. You don't get to set it yourself. You can only access it through the [UniqueID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx) of the control.

Comment: the "UniqueID" is a readonly property, i don't get why you mention it.This is not the answer for me, as the reply bellow solved my problem, and not this one

Comment: @Shide, I mentioned it because the value of that (read-only, yes) property is used as the value for the `name` attribute of the element. That's what I meant by *you don't get to set it yourself*.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution, without knowing a bit more about your code, is to use a server side Html control rather than an ASP.NET web control by adding the runat="server" attribute to the Html markup:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" runat="server" />
```

You can then specify the id dynamically in the code behind at runtime from which the name attribute is inferred from:

```
myHiddenField.ID = "CodebehindName";
myHiddenField.Value = "myValue";
```

This will result in the following output:

```
<input name="CodebehindName" type="hidden" id="CodebehindName" value="myValue" />
```

Comment: This solution gives mixed results: If used in a plain vanilla aspx file the name attribute is indeed "CodebehindName". If used in a more complex situation (e.g. using a master page and the field is located within a ContentPlaceHolder control) then the name attribute is automatically set and the value given in code behind is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Another unorthodox method to deal with it is to set the name attribute client side.  This is useful if you are posting to a third party such as PayPal.

jQuery EG:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#BusinessHid').prop('name', 'business')
        $('#CurrencyHid').prop('name', 'currency_code')
        $('#InvoiceHid').prop('name', 'invoice')
        $('#AmountHid').prop('name', 'amount')
    })
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="BusinessHid" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="CurrencyHid" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InvoiceHid" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="AmountHid" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the HiddenField control and use a Label instead, give it a name (an id), make it invisible, and store your text into it:

```
label = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label() {
 Text = "Here my hidden text",
};
label.Attributes.Add("id", "MyHiddenFieldID");
label.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
myParentControl.Controls.Add(label);
```

Get your hidden field in your javascript with:

```
var myHiddenField = document.getElementById("MyHiddenFieldID");
```

Comment: -1, main idea is to persist data betwwen postbacks; a DIV doesn't help.

Comment: you can do this in the page_load event so the form control gets created after postback. You could also just use a literal control and add the whole html eg Literal lit = new Literal(); lit.Text = "<input type='hidden' name='myName' value='" + myValueHere + "'>";

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing this was to set `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the HiddenField and then set the ID to what I want my name to be.

I ended up with ugly IDs but this was a small price to pay to get this to work.